# jQuery selector with ASP.NET controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

iam using ajax in asp.net page for state, city and zip code field. i want this ajax functionality to be generic. i want to use the same ajax functionality for the textbox and label controls with different ids. i tried with cssclassproperty but it applied to both set of controls. the code is following below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {

       $('.csszipcode').blur(function (event) {

           var text = $('.csszipcode').val();

           if (text == "") {


               $('.csslblcity').text("");
               $('.csslblstate').text("");
               return;
           }

           var isValid = /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/.test(text);

           if (!isValid) {
               $('.csslblcity').text("");
               $('.csslblstate').text("");


               return;
           }


           $.ajax({

               type: "POST",
               url: "/SERVICES/DataService.asmx/getCityState",
               data: "{'zipcode': '" + $('.csszipcode').val() + "'}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (msg) {
                   AjaxSucceeded(msg);
               },
               error: AjaxFailed

           });

       });

   });

   function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
       var city = result.d.split(':')[0];
       var state = result.d.split(':')[1];

       if (city != null && state != null) {

           $('.csslblcity').html(city);
           $('.csslblstate').html(state);
       }
       else {
           $('.csslblcity').text("");
           $('.csslblstate').text("");

       }
   }

   function AjaxFailed(result) {
       alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
   }

</script>
```

the html codes are following. i want to apply the ajax functionality for the following two
textboxes. how can i differentiate which is currently active.

```
<asp:textbox id="txtzipcode" runat="server" cssclass="csszipcode"></asp:textbox>
<asp:textbox id="txtcandacode" runat="server" cssclass="csszipcode"></asp:textbox>
```

Comment: Did you tried use ClientId? Checkc here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Comment: You're *really* going to have to clarify this question. As it is, it makes no sense.

Comment: I can help you on this, but you'll beed to start voting on some of your other answers before I do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you are asking.

You say:

> i want to use the same ajax
>   functionality for the textbox and
>   label controls with different ids.

Implying that you want the same functionality for textboxes and labels, but then say:

> i tried with cssclassproperty but it
>   applied to both set of controls. the
>   code is following below

Implying that you don't want it to apply to textboes and labels.

Can you clarify?

Also, post your HTML (preferably the rendered code). This will help us ascertain how best to achieve what you want.

I can take a stab at an answer but given that I'm not sure what you are asking, may probably be wrong.

ASP.NET label controls are rendered as `<span>` HTML elements. To differentiate between textboxes and spans with the same class, use the following selectors

```
$('input.csszipcode')
$('span.csszipcode')
```

To narrow the selector to textboxes only, try this:

```
$('input:text.csszipcode')
```

If this isn't what you are after can you add more clarification?